# How can I connect the between web application with an application?

Tags: android, json, web, firebase-realtime-database

1) I have a web application. This web app is for a user to buy a point.

2) I have an android application for parking payment. Payment is based on point that user buy from the admin. Since I made two things which are web app for admin and android app for user, so I will have two database for each one right?

3) So, how can I transfer the point that user buy from the admin to an android application? Is this thing has to do with JSON fetch or pass data?

4) Basically I want the user to get the point from the web application? Your answer will be really helpful to me, thank you :)

Comment: Since you already tagged with firebase-database, that would be a perfect place to share data for a user between the web and Android apps. If you take the codelabs for [web](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) and [android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/), you'll see that they share the same data structure. That allows the apps on the different platforms to look at the same data.

Comment: How can I share data between web application and android application?

Comment: You share the data by having the web app and android app talking to the same (cloud hosted) database. It's really not more complex than that. Please give it a try based on the codelabs I shared earlier. If you get stuck while implementing, share where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is design issue. Your mobile app and the web app don’t have to be two separate. 
You can have one application with one database that both web and mobile point to.

If you’re using Android look into ionic framework that can help you code one codebase targeting both web and mobile.

See
https://ionicframework.com

https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-your-first-mobile-app-with-angularjs-and-ionic

Comment: The web based already can connected to the database that android app used. Thank you @Salah- 1

Comment: Ionic now supports React to boot!. I am pivoting in that direction for my own app.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build a single server for both your admin and your app. Both will have a single database that is controlled by your server. Your app will request the same server to redeem points and your admin will request the server to add points. You can use retrofit library in android for making api calls to your server

Comment: Happy to help. Please upvote my answer if i have helped you in nay way

Answer (score 0):

The web application and the android application must connect to the same database on the server. In the android application, to you get the data via json, you must use asynctask to download the server information or use libraries like Retrofit or volley that facilitate the handling of json.